# Ecommerce search by brand, category or name

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I am building an e-commerce site, I am starting from scratch. First I am making my search page, I have displayed my data in a table, now I have made an input field and a search button. I am stuck with building the query, I want the input field to search (category/brand/name) e.g. i can enter nike or shirts or green. I have a single table (products).

How can i show single name like shown in image, where there are three kind of things.

**My Tables Structure:**

**INVENTORY**

```
id
product_id
color
size
quantity
```

**PRODUCT**

```
product_id
product_name
product_category
product_sub_cat
product_details
```

**MY QUERY**

```
SELECT p.outlet_id, p.product_id, p.product_name, p.product_sku, p.product_price, p.product_actual_price, p.product_category, p.product_sub_category, i.inventory_size, i.inventory_color,  i.product_id, i.inventory_quantity  FROM products as p
INNER JOIN inventory AS i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
```

**WHAT I WANT**

[image]

Comment: What if a product has more than one category?

Comment: i would appreciate if i get answer to this particular scenario